# How to apply a style to multiple edit box controls at once?

Tags: android

I have this:

```
          <EditText
            android:id="@+id/something"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/something"
            android:inputType="something"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_text_style"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_margin="10px"
            android:padding="10px" />
```

Can I apply the 2nd part of it starting with `android:maxLines="1` to multiple editbox controls without having to specify all these properties? Can I save them somewhere and then just refer to them? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `res/values/styles.xml` you can create a custom style:

```
<style name="MyEditTextStyle">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_text_style</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Then you can use it on each `EditText` as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/something"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/something"
    android:inputType="something"
    style="@style/MyEditTextStyle" />
```

More details are available [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

P.S. Avoid using `px`. You should take care of screen density and use `dp`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for details.